# Minimum amount of different money bills such that any payment has the smallest number of bills?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Take the integers on $A=[1,5]$. What is the smallest set that can generate the whole set via positive linear combinations? The answer is clearly $\{1\}$ but consider the set $\{1,2\}$ and observe:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
{1}&{=(1)\cdot1}&{=(1)\cdot1}\\ 
{2}&{=(2)\cdot1}&{=(1)\cdot2}\\ 
{3}&{=(3)\cdot1}&{=(3)\cdot1}\\ 
{4}&{=(4)\cdot1}&{=(2)\cdot2}\\ 
{5}&{=(5)\cdot1}&{=(2)\cdot2+(1)\cdot1}
\end{array}$$

The maximum value of the sum of the coefficients of all the linear combinations with $1$ is $5$. The maximum value of the sum of the coefficients of all the linear combinations with $1,2$ is $3$.

So, what is the minimum subset of $[1,n]$ such that the sum of the positive coefficients of each linear combination for all integers in $[1,n]$ is minimum?

I accidentally thought about this problem today but I have no clue on how to solve it. I was thinking about money bills: Here, we have bills for $1,2,5,10,20,50,100$. I thought: What is the minimum amount of different money bills from $1$ to $100$ we need to have such that any payment has the smallest number of bills?

Comment: If we have bills for all integers from $1$ to $100$, then each payment takes $1$ bill, which is clearly the minimum.

Comment: Just try the largest number of the largest bills until the largest bill is more than what's left. Then try the next smaller and the next smaller until only ones will pay of the total amount.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes but this is also the largest set of bills. We need smallest set of bills and smallest sum of coefficients.

Comment: I don't think you can minimize both; that was my point.  With fewer than $100$ denominations, the total number of bills will be more than $100$.  You need some additional condition.

Comment: The question is quite vague. As saulspatz states in his comment, the whole set gives you sum of coefficients always as $1$, which cannot be done for any smaller set. What do you exactly mean by minimize two values? Which one of these pairs would you say is minimum, $(2,5)$ or $(1,7)$ or $(3,4)$?